# Generate .py stubs from Python C/C++ module

Tags: c++, python, module, generator, stub

When I examined, for example, `__builtin__.py` module source, or some modules from numpy, I found that actually they contain only stubs of classes and methods with documentation. As far as I understand, they were generated by 'something'. This 'something' is mentioned in header of such modules, for example `__builtin__.py` contains '`# from (built-in) by generator 1.96`'
So. What is this 'generator' and where can it be obtained? Such stubs are handy: I can look up signature of a method right in my IDE without reading separate web documentation.